# How to apply an animation to an item whenever it appears in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want the animation specified in the layoutAnimation to work every time an item comes into view inside of my recyclerview. Currently, the following animation works as intended and is applied the first time the view is drawn. However, after scrolling inside my recycerview, the item does not have the animation applied to it--this is not desired. I want the item to have the animation applied to it every time the item comes into view--whether recycled or drawn for the first time.

Does the layoutAnimation not work in this way? Is this for only the initial placement of the layout inside the parent?

My item that gets applied to recyclerview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/item_life_event_id"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/animation">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewEventTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/animation_small"
    android:animationOrder="normal"/>
```

animation_small.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="0"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="100%"
        android:fromYScale="100%"
        android:toXScale="50%"
        android:toYScale="50%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        />

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set animation in your recycleview rather the seting in item try out with below code :

res/anim/layout_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/item_animation_fall_down"
    android:animationOrder="normal"
    android:delay="5%" />
```

animation_small.xml

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500">

<translate
    android:fromYDelta="-20%"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    />

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:toAlpha="1"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    />

<scale
    android:fromXScale="105%"
    android:fromYScale="105%"
    android:toXScale="100%"
    android:toYScale="100%"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    />
```

Now you have to use this in you recyclerview.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: I believe I have looked at this solution before in another answer. Unfortunately, this does not do anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the above XML layouts, I added animations inside of my adapter for the item within the recyclerview like so:

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull MyHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.my_animation);
    holder.itemView.startAnimation(anim);
}

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull MyHolder holder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
    holder.itemView.clearAnimation();
}
```